# Python slow at accepting connections via sockets

Tags: python, sockets

### So first I'll describe what I am doing.

A game is providing a webinterface but only on IPv4 and I would like people out in the internet to reach it too. From my ISP I however only get public IPv6. And since I couldn't find anything on the internet to translate requests and responses I wrote a little app that does. So IPv6 requests get forwarded to the webserver and the webservers responses get translated back to IPv6. That's working fine.
The only troubling bit is that... not all requests get detected or whatever is happening, like I first visit the webpage and sometimes it just hangs and says that it's waiting for a style.css file but when I look at the console output there's no reported connection. And generally there's just a whole lot of delay when you try doing something with the webinterface.

Then here is my code: (A word of warning I don't really know what everything with the networking exactly does, the stuff around the sending I especially don't quite understand if it's even needed, I just found it online)

```py
def handle_request(return_address):
    ipv4side = socket.create_connection(("127.0.0.1", 7245))
    request = return_address.recv(2048)
    print(request)
    request = str(request, 'utf-8')
    p = re.compile('\\[[^]]*]:7250')
    m = p.search(request)
    request = request.replace(request[m.start():m.end()], '127.0.0.1:7245')
    request = request.encode('utf-8')

    msg_len = len(request)
    totalsent = 0
    while totalsent < msg_len:
        sent = ipv4side.send(request[totalsent:])
        if sent == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        totalsent += sent
    while True:
        response = ipv4side.recv(2048)

        if len(response) == 0:
            ipv4side.close()
            return

        msg_len = len(response)
        totalsent = 0
        while totalsent < msg_len:
            sent = return_address.send(response[totalsent:])
            if sent == 0:
                raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
            totalsent += sent


ipv6side = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ipv6side.bind((IPV6, 7250))
ipv6side.listen(20)
ipv6side.settimeout(30)

while True:
    try:
        connected_socket = ipv6side.accept()[0]
        print("NEW CONNECTION!" + str(connected_socket))
        Thread(target=handle_request, args=(connected_socket,)).start()
    except socket.timeout:
        print("nothing new...")
```

I hope anyone can help me with this :D

Comment: HTTP is allowed to use the same connection for more than one request. The browser probably sent the second request on the first connection, and your program never tried to receive it.

Comment: I had it that style before and it didn't work at all.
And when I restart the thing it somehow picks the request out of thin air and then it works until it doesn't anymore

Comment: if you don't *have to* write your own program, have you tried using some program that can do this already, like `socat`? something like `socat tcp6-listen:7250,fork tcp-connect:127.0.0.1:7245`

Comment: So there do exist programs that do this already! I just couldn't find any haha
But is there a equivalent of socat that works on Windows?


Edit: Found something, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem! (I think)

So, I followed what user253751 said about how HTTP is allowed to use the same connection for more than one request so I made adjustments and also so that that works it now has to detect the end-of-response/request (eor) for the responses and requests.
First thing I did was wrap the whole handle_request code in a while statement for the multiple requests on one connection thing.

For the end-of-response I am using regex

```py
eor = re.compile('\\r\\n\\r\\n\\Z')
```

and then at the appropriate place:

```py
eorm = eor.search(str(response, 'ISO-8859-1', ignore)) # I replaced the utf-8
                                                       # by the correct ISO-
                                                       # 8859-1 used for HTTP 
                                                       # just to be safe

if eorm or len(response) == 0:
    safe_send(return_address, response)
    ipv4side.close()
    break
```

And for the end-of-request it's basically the same just it only looks that the request is 0 length.
The code responsible for sending I put into the safe_send function that takes a connection and a msg.

Aaand I coded it so that in case the server aborts a connection for some reason and thus throws an error when trying to receive, it resends the request on a new connection.

```py
try:
    response = ipv4side.recv(2048)
except ConnectionAbortedError:
    ipv4side = socket.create_connection(("127.0.0.1", 7245))
    safe_send(ipv4side, request)
    continue
```

I hope this is a good explanation :]